# Delphi RTTI GetMethod('create') not working

Tags: delphi, rtti

i have a simple procedure to find a class constructor using RTTI. But i don't know why, is throwing me an acces violation exception.

```
procedure simplemethod;
var
   QRClass : TClass;
   ClaseRTTI : TRttiInstanceType;
   metodo : TRttiMethod; 
   Ctx: TRttiContext;
begin
  ctx := TRttiContext.Create;
  ClaseRTTI := Ctx.FindType('unitname.classname') as TRttiInstanceType;
  QRClass := ClaseRTTI.MetaclassType;
  metodo := ClaseRTTI.GetMethod('create');
  ctx.Free; 
end;
```

The 'create' constructor is inherited and not declared in unitname.classname.

**EDIT**

Here i have the actual code

```
 function TFDatosDocumentacionOficial.GenerarDocumentacion(p_idtabla, p_id, p_idserie_documento,
                                                           p_idtdocumento, p_idusuario, p_idinforme : integer;
                                                           p_subsis : string = '') : integer;
 var
   QRClass : TClass;
   FQRPlan : TFQRPlanFR3;
   FQRMDPlan : TFQRMDPlanFR3;
   Instancia : TValue;
   ClaseRTTI : TRttiInstanceType;
   fichero : string;
   filtro: string;
   //
   metodo : TRttiMethod;
 begin
   QTDocumento.open;
   QSerieDocumento.open;
   if QTDocumento.locate('IDTDOCUMENTO', p_idtdocumento, []) then
   begin
     fichero := QTDocumentoDESCRIPCION.asString+' '+QSerieDocumentoDESCRIPCIONCORTA.asString+'_'+QSerieDocumentoPROX_NUM.asString+'.pdf';
     ClaseRTTI := utiles.findAnyClass( QTDocumentoQR.AsString );
     QRClass := ClaseRTTI.MetaclassType;
     metodo := ClaseRTTI.GetMethod('create');
     Instancia := metodo.Invoke(QRClass,[self,1,p_idinforme]);
   end;
end;
```

and findAnyClass is

```
function FindAnyClass(const Name: string): TRttiInstanceType;
var
  ctx: TRttiContext;
  typ: TRttiType;
  list: TArray<TRttiType>;
begin
  Result := nil;
  ctx := TRttiContext.Create;
  list := ctx.GetTypes;
  for typ in list do
    begin
      if typ.IsInstance and (EndsText(Name, typ.Name)) then
        begin
          Result := Ctx.FindType(typ.asInstance.DeclaringUnitName+'.'+typ.Name) as TRttiInstanceType;
          break;
        end;
    end;
  ctx.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Method has to be public or published or `$RTTI` has to be used to change the visibility for rtti generation. See http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/RTTI_directive_(Delphi)

Comment: The create is public

Comment: Then check if `FindType` actually returns something - my second and last guess without any further code provided by you is that the class either got removed by the linker because it was not referenced anywhere and thus could not be found or that something else is wrong such as the class being in the implementation part of the unit.

Comment: QRClass contains the correct class, so FindType is returning it. The class is used in other units of the proyect and works fine.

Comment: If we had a [mcve] we would not have to guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your `FindAnyClass()` function is faulty.

You should be returning

```
Result := typ.AsInstance;
```

Instead of

```
Result := Ctx.FindType(typ.asInstance.DeclaringUnitName+'.'+typ.Name) as TRttiInstanceType;
```

They are the same `TRttiInstanceType` object, so the `FindType()` is redundant.

But, more importantly, you are returning a `TRttiInstanceType` object that is owned by `TRttiContext` and gets freed when `TRttiContext` is destroyed.

The caller is not checking if `ClaseRTTI` is `nil`, but assuming it is not `nil` in your situation, accessing `ClaseRTTI.MetaclassType` and calling `ClaseRTTI.GetMethod()` are operating on an **invalid object**.  That is why `GetMethod()` crashes.  But even if it didn't, the behavior of calling `metodo.Invoke()` would be **undefined** and likely to crash as well.

You *MUST* keep the `TRttiContext` in scope until you are done access its RTTI data.

---

A safer option would be to have `FindAnyClass()` return the metaclass `TClass` instead, and then the caller can simply type-cast it and call its `Create()` constructor normally instead of via RTTI, eg:

```
function FindAnyClass(const Name: string): TClass;
var
  ctx: TRttiContext;
  typ: TRttiType;
begin
  Result := nil;
  for typ in ctx.GetTypes do
  begin
    if typ.IsInstance and (EndsText(Name, typ.Name)) then
    begin
      Result := typ.AsInstance.MetaclassType;
      break;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Then you can do this:

```
// tweak this to match your actual code as needed...
type
  TQRBase = class(... whatever ...)
  public
    constructor Create(... params ...); virtual;
  end;

  TQRClass = class of TQRBase;

// derive other classes from TQRBase as needed...

...

function TFDatosDocumentacionOficial.GenerarDocumentacion(p_idtabla, p_id, p_idserie_documento,
                                                           p_idtdocumento, p_idusuario, p_idinforme : integer;
                                                           p_subsis : string = '') : integer;
var
  QRClass : TQRClass;
  Instancia : TQRBase;
  ...
begin
  QTDocumento.open;
  QSerieDocumento.open;
  if QTDocumento.locate('IDTDOCUMENTO', p_idtdocumento, []) then
  begin
    ...
    QRClass := utiles.findAnyClass( QTDocumentoQR.AsString ) as TQRClass;
    Instancia := QRClass.Create(Self, 1, p_idinforme);
    ...
  end;
end;
```